# Difference between `WebGLRenderingContext.{isEnabled|getParameter}` for capabilities?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I noticed there appears to be two ways to query whether a capability is enabled: `isEnabled` and `getParameter`. `isEnabled` seems to be the *actually* correct way to check whether a capability is enabled, but I'm attempting to understand what it means to call `getParameter` with a capability.

Below is my test code that iterates through each capability defined in WebGL1, attempts to enable the capability, then checks whether the return value of `isEnabled` matches the return value of `getParameter`.

```js
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    ,   gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl')
    ,   capabilities = [
            'BLEND',
            'CULL_FACE',
            'DEPTH_TEST',
            'DITHER',
            'POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL',
            'SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE',
            'SAMPLE_COVERAGE',
            'SCISSOR_TEST',
            'STENCIL_TEST'
        ];

    for (var i = 0; i < capabilities.length; i++) {
        var capability = gl[capabilities[i]];

        gl.enable(capability);

        var isEnabledResult = gl.isEnabled(capability)
        ,   getParameterResult = gl.getParameter(capability);

        if (isEnabledResult !== getParameterResult) {
            console.log(capabilities[i], isEnabledResult, getParameterResult);
        }
    }
```

- With WebGL1 on Chrome I receive the following (`STENCIL_TEST` will be removed here if the stencil buffer is enabled while creating the context):

  ```
  SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE true null
  SAMPLE_COVERAGE true null
  STENCIL_TEST true false
  ```
- With WebGL1 on Firefox, IE11, and Edge (regardless of stencil buffer being enabled):

  ```
  SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE true null 
  SAMPLE_COVERAGE true null
  ```
- With WebGL2 on Chrome (`STENCIL_TEST` will be removed here if stencil buffer is enabled):

  ```
  STENCIL_TEST true false
  ```
- With WebGL2 on Firefox, I receive nothing.

So based on these results I have a couple questions:

- Which of these browsers has the correct behavior for `gl.getParameter(gl.STENCIL_TEST)`? If Chrome's behavior is correct, why would `gl.isEnabled(gl.STENCIL_TEST)` and `gl.getParameter(gl.STENCIL_TEST)` not return the same value?
- Why did the behavior for `SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE` and `SAMPLE_COVERAGE` only become allowable in WebGL2? I have a feeling the answer to this is simply "because the WebGL1 specification didn't allow it," but it seems inconsistent with the other capabilities, especially provided that it returns a value for `isEnabled`. Perhaps there is a historical reason for this in OpenGL ES?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything you can query with `isEnabled` can also be queried with `getParameter`. Specifically, this should always be true:

```
function TestPname(pname) {
  var expected = gl.isEnabled(pname);
  var error = gl.getError();
  if (error)
    return error == gl.INVALID_ENUM;

  var actual = gl.getParameter(pname);
  error = gl.getError();
  if (error)
    return false;

  return actual == expected;
}
```

GLES 2.0.25 p134:

> However, state variables for which `IsEnabled` is listed as the query command can also be obtained using `GetBooleanv`, `GetIntegerv`, and `GetFloatv`.

These sound like bugs in `getParameter` behavior.